# create a .yaml config file to use jointPositionController in order to control a robot joints

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i was following this tutorial : http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control to create a .yaml config file in order to control my robot's joints, so that did work for me but i want to create just one controller to controll many joints.

i wrote this code but the controllers didn't want to be load :

joint_position_controller:

type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController

```
joints: joint1

          joint2

          joint3

          joint4

pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
```

any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295500/create-a-.yaml-config-file-to-use-jointpositioncontroller-in-order-to-control-a-robot-joints/) by [samo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34944/samo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-06-28**:
Do you mean , how to control the joints ?

There are two ways , Publish from [CLI](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher)

or Use [rqt_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_reconfigure)

**Comment by [samo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34944/samo/) on 2018-06-28**:
Thank you. yeah, i used rqt_gui in order to control the joints and that worked for me, but i want to declare just one controller, so when i want to publish from a node i can use just one topic to publish in all my joints.

did you understand me? if there is any question i'm listenning.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-06-29**:
@samo please stop bumping your question. If someone can answer, he/she will probably have done so...

**Comment by [samo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34944/samo/) on 2018-06-29**:
@mgruhler got it, and sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not possible with the `effort_controllers/JointPositionController`. This is intended for a single joint.

However, there is also [an `effort_controllers/JointGroupPositionController`.](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/effort_controllers/html/classeffort__controllers_1_1JointGroupPositionController.html) I don't have personal experience, but this might do what you want.

Syntax for the yaml is (according to [this example](https://github.com/personalrobotics/herb_launch/blob/master/config/ros_control_controllers.yaml)) :

```
type: "position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController"
joints:
 - joint_1
 - joint_2
pid_gains:
  joint_1: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
  joint_2: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [samo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34944/samo/) on 2018-07-06**:
thanks, i tried what you told me here but it gives me an error "load_parameters: unable to set parameters (last param was [/pid_gains/elbow/i=1]): cannot marshal None unless allow_none is enabled"

**Comment by [samo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34944/samo/) on 2018-07-06**:
do you know what kind of error is this, and how to solve it?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-07-06**:
see e.g. #q165686